# Combining two lists in the {x,y} format

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of x and y values. How can I combine them so that I get the following:

```
x={x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}

y={y1,y2,y3,y4,y5}

mylist={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},{x4,y4},{x5,y5}}
```

Answer (score 3):

this is a repeat of another question, but the answer is:

```
mylist = Transpose @ {x,y}
```